# Std function with unknown return type

Tags: c++, std-function

I'm trying to declare a std function without directly knowing the return type.

Obviously, it will be known at compile time, but I can't find a right way to declare it.

On top of that, I need to create a container which will contain values from the return of this function.

```
template <typename... Args>
class Sample
{
public:
    Sample(Args... args, std::function</*unknown return type*/(Args...)> fnct) :
        _inputBuff(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))

    { }

    std::tuple<Args...>                     _inputBuff;
    std::vector</*unknown return type*/>    _resultBuff;

};
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: When it is known, and how ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm trying to find an elegant way to do it but, yes, this is an option.

Comment: @Wimps: Seems like quite a simple problem, no?

Comment: @Jarod42 When I will call the constructructor

Comment: @Wimps: That don't make no sense. You call a constructor of a *type*. You don't have a type until you define it. Therefore you cannot base the definition of a type based on its constructor call.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You never "call a constructor", of any type.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Pretty sure he means at the point of instantiation/usage. i.e. he will declare an e.g `Sample<std::string, int, char, bool>`. After all, there is no other option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't know the function arguments either, and solved that problem with a template parameter (well, a parameter pack, since there are zero or more).

Just do the same for the return type!

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class Sample
{
public:
    Sample(Args... args, std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> fnct) :
        _inputBuff(std::forward_as_tuple(args...))

    { }

    std::tuple<Args...>     _inputBuff;
    std::vector<ReturnType> _resultBuff;
};
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/580a3c8c666633bb))

Comment: I agree, there is no other options. Thx !

Comment: @Wimps: Not sure why you're looking for any. Do you envision a problem with this conventional approach?

Comment: I wanted to find a way to declare my function and container without asking the user about the type he need to put in it

Comment: @Wimps: So what you're really asking is how to get template parameter deduction at the callsite.

Comment: @Wimps: That's a limitation of C++ unfortunately.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not in c++17. It has been a limitation but soon not.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Hmm, nice (and confirmed). Didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

You could accept a callable type in your template arguments instead of a list of parameters. That will allow you to send any function or function object and to inspect the return type:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
struct Sample {
    Sample(F fnct, Args... args) :
        _inputBuff{std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)} { }

    using Result = std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>;

    std::tuple<Args...> _inputBuff;
    std::vector<Result> _resultBuff;
};
```

In order to ease construction of that class, you can introduce a make function that will deduce parameters (note that it can become a deduction guide in C++17):

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto makeSample(F&& fnct, Args&&... args) {
    return Sample<std::decay_t<F>, Args...>{std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```